# web technique for lookup another table

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to web development and I've been studying cakephp and I have this situation where I want to know the best practice.

Imagine a user creating a new Customer in the application, in the form he has to choose the customer's sales group, and this table has so many records, that's using a drop down list isn't a viable option.

I was thinking in the user press a button, then open a modal window. This new window would have a grid, with search options (for filtering the data) and the user would choose one, and go back to the original form, bringing back the sales group selected by the user.

What's the name of this technique, and is it a good option? How to do this in cakephp?

Best regards﻿

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the front-end, so it doesn't matter if you are using CakePHP or another PHP framework.

What you want to do is make an ajax call to the server on opening the modal window, so it populates its' contents with your grid. Then, proceed as planned.

On the other hand, you can use something like Select2. This way you can have searchable drop-down menu right in your page and the user won't need to open a modal window. It's just more convenient for the user.

You can check the examples for Select2 [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).